# How to say copyrighted material in Japanese?

Tags: translation

How do I say copyrighted material in Japanese?

Is 著作権のある資料 a good translation?

I want to say that uploading copyrighted material is prohibited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that would be the most natural phrase in Japanese.  The whole sentence should look like:

> 「[著作権]{ちょさくけん}のある[資料]{しりょう}をアップロードすることは[禁]{きん}じられている。」　or
>
> 「著作権のある資料のアップロードは禁じられている。」